# Kohana ORM reverse lookup on one-to-many

Tags: php, orm, kohana

Does Kohana ORM have a reverse relationship lookup.

For example:

Model `User` has `user_id, name`

Model `Post` has `post_id, post, user_id`

I have a `user` object and want to get all related `Posts`

Thanks, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer - yes you can do it.
For a relation *belongs to* (`post`) - *has many* (`user`) you can load either the user from the post:

```
$post = ORM::factory('post', $post_id);
$user = $post->user;
```

or the posts from the user:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', $user_id);
$posts = $user->posts->find_all();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation of [ORM relationships](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships). I hope this will help you.